# JUnit Testing Instance Methods of Class with Main Method

Tags: java, testing, junit

I've been working on this Java application that is a small game. It is all encapsulated in one class called Wege, which has a main method that depending on the arguments passed, creates a game board of specified rows and columns and cards, and has a default setup if there are no arguments. Wege also has a start method to handle JavaFX GUI, and a bunch of instance methods that implement the gameplay rules.

I'm required to JUnit test all of these instance gameplay methods, but not the main or start methods. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to test Wege in the first place, as I get ExceptionInInstance errors whenever I try to instance Wege (I'm guessing due to its static main method), and I'm unable to access any instance methods.

I tried doing `Wege w = new Wege()`, which throws an `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

I tried using `Wege.main(s)`, where `s` is the args, which gives a null pointer exception.

Normally when I test, I can always just instance the class and then do `Assert(MyClass.method())`. That's not possible here, and I'm not sure how to get past it to test my methods. Here is part of the Wege main method:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        
        // if no inputs are given set the board to the default 6x6 and default card pile
        if (args.length == 0){
            setRows(6);
            setColumns(6);
            setCardNumbers(12, 2, 3, 3);
        }
        
        // if one input then set the board to 6x6 and add special cards dependent on the value inputted
        else if(args.length == 1){/*
            Stuff
        */}
        
        // if two inputs then sets the board dimensions to the two values
        else if(args.length == 2){/*
            Stuff
        */}
        
        // if three inputs then sets the board dimensions to the two values and adds the amount of special cards that was given
        else if(args.length == 3){/*
            Stuff
        */}

        
        Application.launch(args);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to check how to initialize Wege class and test it in JUnit framework.  It is better if you could paste the complete codes of Wege class.

Comment: The [doc for that exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html) indicates you have an error in a static item in your `Wege` class. You need to show that code.